# Conectar PosgreSQL 9.3 con Crystal Report en Visual Studio 2015

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

Omito contar la cantidad de horas que llevo invertidas para resolver este problema pero ahi va:
Tengo un report en crystal report y necesito conectarlo a la bbdd PosgreSQL 9.3 pero sin ODBC, a traves de un connectionstring o como sea, el caso es que en la aplicación utilizo el conctor NPGSQL v3.2.1 para trabajar con la bbdd pero no se como hacer que el informe CR se conecte a la BBDD.
el IDE que uso es VS2015 PROF y SO Windows7 prof 64bits.
¿Me pueden echar una mano?
gracias.

Comment: Sigo estancado con el problema, necesito acceder a una bbdd PosgreSQL 9.3 desde un informe de Crystal Report, sigo con Visual Studio 2015 prof. en una función pública creo un DataSet y lo lleno con los datos pero no se como llamarlo desde el report. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente desistí de intentar conectar a una BBDD PostgreSQL con Crystal Report, pero al intentar conectar por medio del ODBC que habia creado el Crystal Report me daba un problema y es que yo etoy usando windows 7 64bits y usaba el odbc de postgreSQL 64 bits, este no es compatible con Crystal Report por lo que tuve que instalar el gestor odbdc de 32bits de postgres para instalarlo tuve que proceder como se indica en este [enlace](http://zosemu.blogspot.com.es/2012/08/solucion-al-problema-con-odbc-pgsql.html) ya que si lo haces por la via normal el controlador no es visible en el momento de crear el ODBC. Espero que no tengan que invertir tanto tiempo como me ha tocado a mi, casi 3 días enteros solo para buscar una solución a este problema. Arjjj :-(